# Bootstrap datepicker not working on div,

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using [bootstrap datepicker](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker) in my HTML.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div>
        <input id="my-date-picker" type="text" class="form-control"  readonly required>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use `$('#my-date-picker').datepicker()` on the input element, all the [bootstrap datepicker methods](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#cleardates) work perfectly.

But when I use

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div id="my-date-picker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly required>
    </div>
</div>
```

the methods do not work. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The id you have to assign to input, not to div

This.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div >
        <input id="my-date-picker" type="text" class="form-control" readonly required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second HTML example doesn't have the `id` attribute on the `input`, which is the element you need to instantiate the `datepicker()` on.

You need to use either this, where the `id` is on the `input` directly:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div>
        <input id="my-date-picker" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" required="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#my-date-picker').datepicker()
```

Or this, where the `id` is on the parent `div` and you select the child `input`:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div id="my-date-picker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" required="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#my-date-picker input').datepicker()
```

Comment: That's using a `datetimepicker()`, not a `datepicker()`. That would imply his example is using a different datepicker library.